# From numpy array of sentences to array of embedding

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp, embedding, word-embedding

I'm learning to use tensorflow and trying to classify text. I have a dataset where each text is associated with a label 0 or 1. My goal is to use some sentence embedding to do the classification. First I've created an embedding from the whole text using the Gnews precompile embedding:

```
embedding = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/gnews-swivel-20dim/1"
hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(embedding, input_shape=[2], dtype=tf.string,
                           trainable=True, output_shape=[None, 20])
```

Now I'd like to try something else (similar to this method http://www.wildml.com/2015/11/understanding-convolutional-neural-networks-for-nlp/) and I wanted to:

- Separate each text into setences.
- Create an array of embeddings for each text, one per sentence.
- Use that as input for my model.

I'm able to separate the texts in sentences. Each text is an array of sentences saved as:

```
[array(['AITA - Getting Hugged At The Bar .',
       'This all happened less than an hour ago..',
       'I was at a bar I frequent and talking to some people I know, suddenly I feel someone from behind me hugging and starting to grind against me.',
       "I know a lot of people at the bar, and assume it's a friend of mine, but when I look down at the shoes I do not recognize them.",
       'I look back and I see a dude I do not know, nor have I ever seen.',
       "He looks back at me, with horror in his eyes, because I'm a dude too...",
       'I feel an urge of rage inside me and shove him in the chest with my elbow so I can get away..',
       'He goes to his table and I go back to mine.',
       'I was with my roommate and his girlfriend.',
       'They asked what happened and I told them, then I see the guy who hugged me looking around for me.',
       'Him and two of his friends come up to us and he says:  .',
       '"I just wanted to apologize, I thought you were someone else.".',
       'I respond, "I understand, just check before you hug people.',
       'Now, please fuck off".',
       'He repeats his last statement, so do I.',
       'This happens one more time and at this point his friends have surrounded me, my roommate is on his feet and I have left my beer at the table.',
       'His friend goes in my face and says.', '.',
       '"He just wanted to apologize, you really shouldn\'t be yelling at us" and starts waiving his finger at me.. We are at a rock bar, it\'s loud, I was speaking louder just to be sure I am heard..',
       'The manager knows me so he comes asking me what happened.',
       'I explain the situation and he speaks with them then he tells me.',
       '.', '"They want to say sorry, can you guys shake hand?', '".',
       '"Yeah sure, I just want them to leave me alone."', '.',
       "Honestly I didn't even want to touch the guy, but whatever.",
       "We shake hands and they go away.. Me and my roommate look at their table and there's no one that looks anything like me.",
       'So, reddit, did I overreact?', 'Am I The Asshole here?'],
      dtype='<U190')
 array(["AITA if i don't want to pay my friend 5 dollars for a slice of pizzaSo, my friend bought herself, our other friend and I a pizza to eat for lunch.",
       'Me and other friend ate 1 slice of pizza from an extra large pizza.',
       'Other friend has already paid my friend that bought the pizza 5 dollars..',
       'I am trying to save money wherever i can, but she really wants me to pay her 5 dollars "so its fair".. AITA?'],
      dtype='<U146')
```

Now when I try to create an embedding from one element of the array it works. Here is my embedding function:

```
def embedding_f(test):
    print("test shape:", test.shape)
    # a = tf.constant(test)
    embedding = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/gnews-swivel-20dim/1"
    hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(embedding, input_shape=[], dtype=tf.string,
                               trainable=True, output_shape=[None, 20])
    ret = hub_layer(test)
    # print(ret)
    return ret.numpy()

# Works
emb = cnn.embedding_f(train_data[0])
```

But if I try to input a batch of data (as will be done later in the pipeline, the program crashes

```
# Crashes
emb = cnn.embedding_f(train_data[0:2])



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-76f4f9171cad> in <module>
----> 1 emb = cnn.embedding_f(train_data[0:2])

~/AITA/aita/cnn.py in embedding_f(test)
     22     hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(embedding, input_shape=[2], dtype=tf.string,
     23                                trainable=True, output_shape=[None, 20])
---> 24     ret = hub_layer(test)
     25     # print(ret)
     26     return ret.numpy()

/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    817           return ops.convert_to_tensor_v2(x)
    818         return x
--> 819       inputs = nest.map_structure(_convert_non_tensor, inputs)
    820       input_list = nest.flatten(inputs)
    821 

/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py in map_structure(func, *structure, **kwargs)
    615 
    616   return pack_sequence_as(
--> 617       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    618       expand_composites=expand_composites)
    619 

/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    615 
    616   return pack_sequence_as(
--> 617       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    618       expand_composites=expand_composites)
    619 

/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _convert_non_tensor(x)
    815         # `SparseTensors` can't be converted to `Tensor`.
    816         if isinstance(x, (np.ndarray, float, int)):
--> 817           return ops.convert_to_tensor_v2(x)
    818         return x
    819       inputs = nest.map_structure(_convert_non_tensor, inputs)

/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in convert_to_tensor_v2(value, dtype, dtype_hint, name)
   1276     ValueError: If the `value` is a tensor not of given `dtype` in graph mode.
   1277   """
-> 1278   return convert_to_tensor(
   1279       value=value,
   1280       dtype=dtype,

/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, dtype_hint, ctx, accepted_result_types)
   1339 
   1340     if ret is None:
-> 1341       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
   1342 
   1343     if ret is NotImplemented:

/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_conversion_registry.py in _default_conversion_function(***failed resolving arguments***)
     50 def _default_conversion_function(value, dtype, name, as_ref):
     51   del as_ref  # Unused.
---> 52   return constant_op.constant(value, dtype, name=name)
     53 
     54 

/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name)
    259     ValueError: if called on a symbolic tensor.
    260   """
--> 261   return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
    262                         allow_broadcast=True)
    263 

/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    268   ctx = context.context()
    269   if ctx.executing_eagerly():
--> 270     t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    271     if shape is None:
    272       return t

/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
     94       dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
     95   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 96   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
     97 
     98 

ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).
```

The error states that it's not possible to convert a Numpy array to a tensor. I've tried changing the input_shape parameter of the KerasLayer to no avail. The only solution I see is to calculate the embedding for each text by looping through all of them one by one before finding the result to the rest of the network but that seems highly inefficient (and requires too much memory for my laptop). Examples I see with word embedding, do it this way however.

What is the correct way to go about getting a list of embedding from multiple sentences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `output_shape` should be set to `[20]` (from https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/api_docs/python/hub/KerasLayer):

```
hub.KerasLayer("/tmp/text_embedding_model",
    output_shape=[20],  # Outputs a tensor with shape [batch_size, 20].
    input_shape=[],     # Expects a tensor of shape [batch_size] as input.
    dtype=tf.string)    # Expects a tf.string input tensor.
```

Using TF 2.4.1 and tensorflow_hub 0.11.0, this works for me:

```
data = np.array(['AITA - Getting Hugged At The Bar .', 'This all happened less than an hour ago..'])
model_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/gnews-swivel-20dim/1"
embedding = hub.KerasLayer(model_url, input_shape=[], dtype=tf.string,
                           trainable=True, output_shape=[20])(data)
```

If you don't want to add layers on top of the KerasLayer, you can also just call

```
model = hub.load(model_url)
embedding = model(data)
```